# iOS: Sharing via UIActivityViewController does not work with UIActivityItemSource

Tags: ios, swift

I wanted to further customize how content is shared from my app and instead of providing `UIActivityViewController` with image and title use the `UIActivityItemSource` protocol to implement methods that provide this content.

So I created extension for my model `Scan` like this:

```
extension Scan: UIActivityItemSource {
    func activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> Any {
        return self.title as Any
    }

    func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType?) -> Any? {
        return self.orderedDocuments.map({ $0.image }) as Any
    }

    func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, thumbnailImageForActivityType activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType?, suggestedSize size: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
        return self.thumbnailImage
    }

    func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, subjectForActivityType activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType?) -> String {
        return "Scan from: \(String(describing: self.created))"
    }
}
```

But when I pass instance of `Scan` to the `UIActivityViewController` it opens but it is empty. I cannot see the title, preview or the actual images.. These methods are getting called.

I am presenting the `UIActivityViewController` like this as there is not much to customize:

```
func share(_ scan: Scan) {

        let shareController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [scan], applicationActivities: nil)

        present(shareController, animated: true)
}
```

The `Scan` is Core Data entity but I tried creating separate class just for sharing and that did not work either.

**EDIT**: So I got some progress with metadata like this:

```
func activityViewControllerLinkMetadata(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> LPLinkMetadata? {
        guard let image = self.orderedDocuments.first?.image else { return nil }
        let imageProvider = NSItemProvider(object: image)
        let metadata = LPLinkMetadata()
        metadata.imageProvider = imageProvider
        metadata.title = title
        return metadata
    }
```

It at least shows proper title and thumbnail. I have seen some apps even displaying subtitle and file size which I guess is not possible for in-memory images?

I still have issues with sharing more than one image.

My updated activity controller methods:

```
func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType?) -> Any? {
        return self.orderedDocuments.first?.image
    }

    func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, dataTypeIdentifierForActivityType activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType?) -> String {
        return kUTTypePNG as String
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

Regarding:

> I have seen some apps even displaying subtitle and file size which I
>   guess is not possible for in-memory images?

It's silly, but can be done with:

```swift
linkMetaData.originalURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "Insert whatever info here")
```

For example, for a result like this (custom thumbnail, custom title and subtitle with file size):

[image: myBaby]

... the code is:

```swift
func activityViewControllerLinkMetadata(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> LPLinkMetadata? {

    let linkMetaData = LPLinkMetadata()

    // Thumbnail
    linkMetaData.iconProvider = NSItemProvider(object: someValidUIImage)

    // Title
    linkMetaData.title = "Ohay title!"

    // Subtitle with file size
    let prefix = "PNG Image"

    let fileSizeResourceValue = try! someValidURL.resourceValues(forKeys: [.fileSizeKey])
    let fileSizeInt = fileSizeResourceValue.fileSize

    let byteCountFormatter = ByteCountFormatter()
    byteCountFormatter.countStyle = .file
    let fileSizeString = byteCountFormatter.string(fromByteCount: Int64(fileSizeInt))

    let suffix = "・\(fileSizeString)"

    //
    linkMetaData.originalURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "\(prefix)\(suffix)")

    return linkMetaData
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You saved me days of investigation. Does anybody have a piece of documentation about the `originalURL`?
Because it looks like, it's (a) writing the URL-String s subtitle, (b) tries to open the URL and either (c) overwrite the metadata with what it gets from the URL, or (d) silently fail and keep the subtitle untouched. 
How many side-effects can be put into one parameter...

Comment: Just a note:  Using `originalURL` as a subtitle (e.g. text not a url) only seems to work if you use `URL(fileURLWithPath:)` in iOS 14, using `URL(String:)` seems to work with iOS 13 only.