# Get data from Share Extension in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, share-extension

Inside my app I have a `CustomShareViewController` and with that the workflow should be like this:

1. User is in Safari on some website and looks up any kind of product
2. User taps on "share" and selects my App
3. I parse data from the current URL and use it/store it inside my app

**Problem:**

How do I get the data in Swift? I managed to get the current `URL` and with that the `HTML` like this:

```
@objc func actionButtonTapped(){

        var html: String?

        if let item = extensionContext?.inputItems.first as? NSExtensionItem,
            let itemProvider = item.attachments?.first,
            itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier("public.url") {
            itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: "public.url", options: nil) { (url, error) in
                if (url as? URL) != nil {

                    html = (self.getHTMLfromURL(url: url as? URL))

                    self.doStuff(html: html)
                }
            }
        }
}
```

But is there any way to get the data that Apple provides? (`image` and `title`) ?

That's the data from Apple I mean:

[image]

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsextensioncontext/1414827-inputitems

Comment: @Paulw11 sorry this is the first time I am using a shareExtension. Could you maybe elaborate on this or explain how I can use it in my case?

Comment: Your view controller has an [extensionContext](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621411-extensioncontext) property. The `inputItems` of this extension context are the items that were shared

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks for your answers but I am still struggling. How exactly would I retrieve the current URL or the data in the first picture? (product name and photo)

Comment: `inputItems` is an array of [`NSExtensionItem`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsextensionitem) - You need to go through the array of items, look at their [attachments](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsitemprovider) to find the data you are after.  I'm afraid there isn't a simple one line of "give me the URL"

Comment: urgh, in my mind I thought this was going to be quite easy. Getting the current URL doesn't seem to be that complicated but I guess it is? Too bad.. Thanks for your help anyway. Unfortunately I am still not getting any further :/ Updated my question, maybe that helps someone

Comment: Updated the answer, found a way to get the URL!

Comment: @Paulw11 do you know how to get the `image` and `title` that apple already provides? (first picture)

Comment: @Chris I needed something similar days ago. Check out my question, the edit has example of `LPLinkMetadata` which could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61291139/ios-sharing-via-uiactivityviewcontroller-does-not-work-with-uiactivityitemsourc

Comment: @Filip thanks man! With that information I found an awesome git-rep that solved my problem!

Comment: @Filip do you maybe know how to get the HTML Content after the Javascript is loaded?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61490069/get-html-content-after-it-is-loaded

Comment: @Chris I am afraid I dont have much experience with sharing extensions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With @Filip's hint I found this Git-Repo:

[URLEmbeddedView](https://github.com/marty-suzuki/URLEmbeddedView)

With this I can simply get the data like this:

```
let urlString = ...
OpenGraphDataDownloader.shared.fetchOGData(urlString: urlString) { result in
    switch result {
    case let .success(data, isExpired):
        // do something
    case let .failure(error, isExpired):
        // do something
    }
}
```