# Get HTML content after it is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, ios, swift

I have a `Share Extension` in which I am getting the `HTML` like this:

```
@objc func actionButtonTapped(){

        var html: String?

        if let item = extensionContext?.inputItems.first as? NSExtensionItem,
            let itemProvider = item.attachments?.first,
            itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier("public.url") {
            itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: "public.url", options: nil) { (url, error) in
                if (url as? URL) != nil {

                    html = (self.getHTMLfromURL(url: url as? URL))

                    self.doStuff(html: html)
                }
            }
        }
}
```

**Problem:**

I get the HTML but not the complete content. How do I get the full `HTML`-`content` of the Website ?

***Update:***

The reason is that I would like to scrape the `price` of any product but some sites dont have the `price` loaded  on the first `HTML-get` ...

This [link](https://www.asos.com/de/levis-skateboarding/levis-skateboarding-sweatshirt-mit-1-4-reiverschluss-in-grau/prd/14868863?clr=grau&colourWayId=16650333&SearchQuery=&cid=13514) is a good example. If you click on the price and inspect it you can see it's in the `class` `current-price`. However if I retrieve the `HTML` with the method above, this `class` is not shown.

Comment: Have you looked at using a URLRequest accompanied with a URLSession? The data element that a session.dataTask returns should be convertible to a String representation which you could then parse.

Comment: @binaryPilot84 Sorry i am not quite following you there. Never used a urlrequest with a urlsession. Could you elaborate on that?:)

Comment: you can go with async-await function call

Comment: You can't scrape the web in iOS without loading a WKWebView.

Answer (score 2):

This function will find HTML from a url string on a background thread (so as not to lock up your UI), then after processing you can update your UI on the main thread:

```
func getHtml(_ urlString: String, completion: @escaping (String?, Error?) -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async(execute: {
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            print("URLError: \(urlString) doesn't seem to be a valid URL")
            return completion(nil, URLError.init(URLError.Code.badURL))
        }

        do {
            let html = try String(contentsOf: url, encoding: .ascii)
            print("HTML: \(html)")
            return completion(html, nil)
        } catch let error {
            print("Error: \(error)")
            return completion(nil, error)
        }
    })
}
```

Usage:

```
getHtml("https://www.google.com", completion: { html, error in
    if let e = error {
        print(e)
        // handle your error
        return
    }
    print(html as Any)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        //update your UI on the main thread
    }
})
```

UPDATE:

You should really be scraping web content on the server end. iOS won't let you do it without presenting a WKWebView.

In iOS, you'll need to load javascript in a WKWebView's didFinish function if you want data like Chrome's "Inspect" feature:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    let doc = webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.documentElement.outerHTML", completionHandler: { html, error in
        print(html)
    })
}
```

Comment: that doesn't really solve my problem. I updated my question, maybe now its more clear.

Comment: @Chris, I've updated my answer, but you can't really do this in iOS without showing a WKWebView. You should be scraping on the server side and then returning that data to your app.

Comment: the problem is that I am using this in s `Share Extension`  so I can acces my app from Safari and add things to my App from that Extension. I dont want to have a `WKWebView` insidie my `ShareExtension`  as that wouldnt really make sense. Do you get me ?

Comment: Hey @Chris, I fully get what you want to do, but unfortunately you need to do it on the server-side. Currently, you can't do it in iOS. Probably because Apple thinks it might cause slows in the user experience with loading pages and parsing them.

Comment: The workaround that I know of is to load the page in a WKWebView and load the Javascript. Maybe there is a way to load a WKWebView without it displaying.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213369/discussion-between-chris-and-elliott-io).

Comment: unfortunately there is no "easy" way to achieve what I asked but you gave the best solution to the problem, so thanks for that

Answer (score 0):

As much I get, there is a problem of loading the Client-side Javascript, for that it will be helpful if you use, `Promise` for that.

P.S.- see if this is useful [Client-side web access](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/client-side-web-scraping-with-javascript-using-jquery-and-regex-5b57a271cb86/)

Comment: thanks for your answer. I never used Javascript before. Is there a way to get this done within Swift ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using a URLSession and a URLRequest:

```
func retrieveHTML(from url: URL, completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    let session = URLSession(configuration: .ephemeral)
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print("Data not found, error encountered: \(error!)")
            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
            let code = httpStatus.statusCode

            if code >= 400 {
                // You can do more here with these codes, but for sake of this example, we'll return
                print("Received error code from HTTP Response. Code: \(code)")
                return
            }

            if code == 301 || code == 302 {
                // You should update the incoming URL as it is moving, but early return not needed
                print("You could log this error here if desired")
            }
        }

        if let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            print("Data found, encoded as string")
            completion(responseString)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

You may still run into errors where the page is not fully loaded, depending on how the JavaScript within the page renders.  This should at least get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: I tried it out and printed `data` I dont think its working right? If you try it with this link for example: https://www.asos.com/de/adidas-performance/adidas-running-terrex-myshelter-gelbe-jacke/prd/12373010?clr=gelb&colourWayId=16384037&SearchQuery=&cid=7113

Comment: the price is in `class=current-price` but if I look for `current-price` or even the `199,95` directly I cant find it in the `retrieved data` from your function? Am I missing something here?

Comment: actually I think the data I get with your code is the exact data I am getting with my function in the question ...

Comment: The HTML retrieved from that is probably not what you want.  That being said, the javascript within that does contain what you need.  That stream had the API URL for what you need to subsequently query and it returns a relatively easy JSON stream.  The link it provided is: /api/product/catalogue/v3/stockprice?productIds=12373010&store=DE&currency=EUR&keyStoreDataversion=j42uv2x-26 which you can append to the base url to make asos.com/api/product/catalogue/v3/stockprice?productIds=12373010&store=DE&currency=EUR&keyStoreDataversion=j42uv2x-26    I would walk the resultant JSON to get the data.

Comment: So How exactly would I get the Price from the example Website ?

Comment: You can use the URLRequest/URLSession example above to extract the API link, start a new URLRequest/URLSession and extract the JSON that the API provides.  You might find it to be easier to examine the productID passed in with the original URL and then submit a request directly to the API using the pattern found above.

Comment: wait what API? sorry never dealt with this topic before. All I want is to get the price. I am doing this by searching `class-names` with `regex` , but like I said in the question some website dont load all the content with the first HTML-Request

Comment: Did you look at the link we pulled in my comment above? That API result should have all the data you're hoping to parse.  The JSON result from the API link provided in my comment above is what the page loads and should provide the price you're looking to show.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213031/discussion-between-chris-and-binarypilot84).